# Getting keystrokes on VLC via AppleScript

Tags: keyboard, applescript, macos, vlc

I have an AppleScript file which works like a charm, except for the part where I use keystrokes to make VLC run fullscreen. The filename has been changed for privacy reasons, but the rest of the code is the exact same. My code goes as this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set MyFile to ((path to me as text) & "File.mkv") as text
end tell
tell application "VLC"
    open MyFile
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "VLC"
        set frontmost to true
        keystroke "f" using command down
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: How is the AppleScript _code_ being executed? Is it saved as an .app and the target `MyFile` placed within the _root_ of the _application bundle_?  I'm asking because, I don't see how your first `tell` _block_ could return a properly formed _pathname_ to the target file otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to tell VLC to perform the keystroke.

```
tell application "VLC"
    open MyFile
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "f" using command down
end tell
```

---

I understand you say the rest of the script works, but without more information, I don't see how.

`path to me` will return the path to the actual script, not the containing folder. This means you'll end up with the equivalent of `path:to:script.scptFile.mkv`, which can't be true. Instead, you need to get the container:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set MyFile to ((container of (path to me) as text) & "File.mkv") as text
end tell
```

This will return `path:to:File.mkv`. Make sure your mkv is actually in this location.

---

Full script:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set MyFile to ((container of (path to me) as text) & "File.mkv") as text
end tell
tell application "VLC"
    open MyFile
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "f" using command down
end tell
```

Comment: sorry, not all the code got copied... it actually was "set MyFile to ((path to me as text) & "Contents:Resources:File.mkv") as text... I'm going to test your script and see how it goes.
*edit* Nice, it worked... thanks!